# Q : Serializer/Deserializer problems

Tags: serialization, deserialization, vhdl, fpga, adc

I want to implement a Serializer/Deserializer (SerDes) in VHDL. Actually, it is more like a simple Shift register. The shift register store a value and shifts to convert information from parallel to serial.The output of the register is 16 bits. It has an 16-bit Parallel input, which allows us to load the register with a new value. The load input allows to load a new value when a falling edge of the clock arrives.

Moreover, I also made a testBench with two SerDes component connected together to implement a sort of loop/ring. Unfortunately, I don't know why when I send a data with the value "1234" from the parallel input I receive "3412" in my parallel output : [waveform testBench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmhAP.png).

Below my code :

SerDes.vhd :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity SerDes is
    generic ( 
        Dbits : integer := 16
           );   
    Port (
           serial_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           clk        : in STD_LOGIC;
           rstn       : in STD_LOGIC;
           load : in STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in STD_LOGIC;
           serial_in : in STD_LOGIC;
           parallel_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0);
           dout : out STD_LOGIC;
           parallel_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0)
          );
end SerDes;

architecture Behavioral of SerDes is

signal rx_counter         : integer   := 0 ;
signal shift_reg : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0);
type   TYPE_STATE is (Idle,ShiftIn); 
signal CURRENT_STATE      : TYPE_STATE := Idle;
signal serial_clock_D : STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

serialization : process(serial_clk,rstn)  --Envoyer une donnée parallèle et la récupérer sur la sortie série

begin 

    if (rstn = '0') then
        shift_reg <= (others => '0');
        rx_counter <= 0;
        serial_clock_D <= '0';
        CURRENT_STATE <= Idle;

    elsif (clk = '1' and clk'event) then     
            case CURRENT_STATE is 

                when Idle =>
                    if (enable = '1') then
                        CURRENT_STATE <= ShiftIn;
                    else
                        CURRENT_STATE <= Idle;     
                    end if;
                    if (load = '1') then
                        shift_reg <= parallel_in;
                    end if;
                    parallel_out <=  shift_reg;
                    rx_counter <= 0;

                when ShiftIn =>       
                      if(serial_clk = '1' and serial_clock_D = '0') then  
                        shift_reg <=  shift_reg(14 downto 0) & serial_in;                            
                      end if;
                       if (rx_counter = Dbits-1) then
                            CURRENT_STATE <= Idle;
                       else 
                            rx_counter <= rx_counter + 1;
                       end if;
            end case;
    end if;
end process;

dout <= shift_reg(15); 

end Behavioral;
```

SERDESTestbench.vhd :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity SERDES_Testbench is
--  Port ( );
end SERDES_Testbench;

architecture Behavioral of SERDES_Testbench is
constant Dbits : integer := 16;

component SerDes is
    generic ( 
        Dbits : integer := 16
           );   
    Port (
           serial_clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           clk        : in STD_LOGIC;
           rstn       : in STD_LOGIC;
           load : in STD_LOGIC;
           enable : in STD_LOGIC;
           serial_in : in STD_LOGIC;
           parallel_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0);
           dout : out STD_LOGIC;
           parallel_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0)
          );
end component;

signal   serial_clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal   clk        : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal   rstn       : STD_LOGIC;
signal   load :  STD_LOGIC := '1';
signal   enable :  STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal   serial_in :  STD_LOGIC;
signal   parallel_in :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal   dout :  STD_LOGIC;
signal   parallel_out :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0);
signal   dout2 :  STD_LOGIC;
signal   parallel_out2 :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(Dbits-1 downto 0);

signal end_of_simu : STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

SR1 : SerDes 
    generic map( 
        Dbits => Dbits
           )  
    Port map(
           serial_clk    => serial_clk,
           clk           => clk,
           rstn          => rstn,
           load          => load,
           enable        => enable,
           serial_in     => dout2,
           parallel_in   => parallel_in,
           dout          => dout,
           parallel_out  => parallel_out
          );

 SR2 : SerDes 
      generic map( 
          Dbits => Dbits
             )  
      Port map(
             serial_clk    => serial_clk,
             clk           => clk,
             rstn          => rstn,
             load          => load,
             enable        => enable,
             serial_in     => dout,
             parallel_in   => parallel_in,
             dout          => dout2,
             parallel_out  => parallel_out2
            );


stimulus : process
  begin
      rstn <= '0';
      wait for 100 ns;
      rstn <= '1';
      wait for 100 ns;
      parallel_in <= X"1234";
      enable <= '1';
      wait;
end process;


clocking : process

begin
  IF end_of_simu /= '1' THEN
      clk <= not clk;
      wait for 5 ns;
  ELSE
      assert false report "end of test" severity note;
      WAIT;
  END IF;
end process;


sclk_gen : process

begin
  IF end_of_simu /= '1' THEN
      serial_clk <= not serial_clk;
      wait for 100 ns;
  ELSE
      assert false report "end of test" severity note;
      WAIT;
  END IF;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your `load` signal never goes low. That's why it keeps loading the `shift_reg`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: How can I affect 0 to load?

Comment: Process serialization counts ion the falling_edge of serial clock lining up with the rising edge of clk, without regard to clock skew. An FPGA vendor might require only one clock edge be used in a process to prevent depending on edge coincidence, which also doesn't map to device primitives (DDR in I/O cells). Use separate processes for different clock domains - processes execute asynchronously to each other. If you added an offset delay to serial_clk in your testbench your simulation would have dout '0's.

Comment: See [Re: can I use falling_edge and rising_edge in a same process block?](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/can-I-use-falling-edge-and-rising-edge-in-a-same-process-block/m-p/348787/highlight/true#M5545) "There are no FPGA registers or latch primitives which sample on the edge of multiple clocks." IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 6.1.3.3 Edge-sensitive storage with one or more clocks "The clock edge conditions shall be mutually exclusive." (Not nested if statements.)